# No group of order 200 is simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory, simple-groups

> Show that any group of order 200 is not a simple group.

I have started with the sylow 5-subgroup, but the sylow 2 subgroups i found that they are 25 subgroup but i couldnt proceed in the proof any more! Please help.

Comment: Well, what did you conclude from looking at the $5$-Sylows?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft there is only one 5-subgroup of order 5 , so it is normal being a unique one ! can i stop here having a nontrivial normal subgroup?

Comment: Right. So why did you move on to the $2$-Sylows?

Comment: the notes i found in the lecture states that my doctor checks all the sylow supgroups ! i dont know really why??

Comment: Was that with this specific example, or another example?

Comment: no no! other examples such as 48, 30 , 56 ! but anyway i can stop when i find a normal nontrivial subgroup , that is i dont need to chek all the normal subgroups?

Comment: Yes. To show that a group is not simple means precisely to show that it has a non-trivial proper normal subgroup.

Answer (score 8):

$|G|=200=2^3\cdot5^2$.  If you want the easy way out, [Burnside's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside_theorem) trivially proves that this is not a simple group.

By Sylow's third theorem, the amount of $5$-subgroups $n_5$ must divide $2^3=8$.  However, $n_5\equiv 1\pmod 5$ so $n_5=1$.

Since conjugation preserves the order of elements and all the elements in the $5$-subgroup are the only elements which can have order that divides $5^2$, the subgroup must be normal in $G$.

Answer (score 6):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;200=2^35^2\\{}\\
\bullet&\;\;2\,,\,2^2\,,\,2^3\neq1\pmod 5\;,\;\;\text{so...}\end{align*}$$

Comment: Wow, some rush to downvote...and also the other answer. Oh, well.

Comment: BTW, about the Burnside Theorem discussion: There is a purely group theoretic proof due to Bender, but as far as I understand it, that proof is way more complicated that the usual one, even though a few improvements have been made over the original (which was in 1972 I think).

Comment: I upvoted again +1, clearly Enas sincerely tries to solve it.

Comment: Thanks @NickyHekster, and yes: I think Enas honestly tries. I though cannot understand the downvote ( not that I give much of a rat's book in group theory, of course...:) )

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, check this https://etd.ohiolink.edu/ap:0:0:APPLICATION_PROCESS=DOWNLOAD_ETD_SUB_DOC_ACCNUM:::F1501_ID:ysu1337975956,attachment for a graduate thesis about Bender's proof. It really looks messy.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice way for seeing that the group $G$ is simple:

> Lemma: Let $G$ be a simple group and $H< G$ such that $[G:H]=n$. Then $G\hookrightarrow A_n$.

Indeed, about the $5-$sylow subgroup of $G$ we see that $200\nmid\frac{8!}{2}$.

Comment: @Serkan: Yes. That $H$ was in my mind. fixed. thanks

Comment: Maybe is very late to talk the Lemma, but how you would prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively let $P$ be a Sylow $5$-subgroup and show that the normal core of $P$ in $G$ cannot be $1$.

Comment: Is there actually a simpler argument for this than for the fact that the $5$-Sylow is normal (ie, is its own normal core)?

Comment: @Serkan: Have a look at mine, plz. ;-)