# No simple groups of given order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups, p-groups

I am trying to show the following:

Prove that there are no simple groups of the given order:

42.

200.

231.

255.

I understand that they need to be broken down into their prime factors.

I was looking to try to understand:
https://www.math3ma.com/blog/4-ways-to-show-a-group-is-not-simple and also what they do in 
[No simple groups of order $90$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3116400/no-simple-groups-of-order-90) 
and [No simple group of order 2016](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577502/no-simple-group-of-order-2016)

What I don't understand, and from all the other problems, is how they determine $n_p\in\{...\}$. If I can understand this step I believe that I will be able to continue with the problem.

What I got for 42 is that the prime factors of $|G|$ are 2,3, and 7. Let $n_p$ denote the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$, this gives us that $n_2\in\{1,3,7,21\}$, $n_3\in\{1,2,14\}$, and $n_7\in\{1,6\}$. Suppose that none of these are 1, (if they are we are done because then there is another normal group, which by definition means that $G$ cannot be simple.) Consider $n_7=6$. This means that there are $7(6-1)=35$ elements of order 7.

I guess I would like to know if I am doing this right, or if there is some fact that I am missing.

Comment: You also have $n_p \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ (see Theorem 3 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems#Theorems)), which further limits possibilities. For instance in your order $42$ example, $n_7 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$ so it can't be $6$. (And similarly, $n_3$ can't be $14$.)

Comment: So does that change $n_7\in\{1,7,14,21\}$?

Comment: $n_7$ must divide $6$ and be $\equiv 1 \pmod{7}$. So the only possibility is $n_7 = 1$.

Comment: Why must it divide 6?

Comment: This is the first bullet in the link I gave. A Sylow $7$ subgroup will have order 7, so it will have index $6$, and $n_p$ must divide this index.

Comment: There are several duplicates here, where the answers are helpful, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583624/no-group-of-order-200-is-simple), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2448606/if-g-is-a-group-of-order-231-show-that-every-element-of-order-11-belongs) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255441/how-can-i-prove-that-every-group-of-n-255-elements-is-commutative).

Comment: Oh ok. So then this gives us that $n_2\in\{1,3,7\}$, $n_3\in\{1,2,7,14\}$, and $n_7\in\{1\}$.