# Prove that groups of order 200 are solvable

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, solvable-groups

Suppose $G$ is a group with $|G| = 200$.  Since $200 = 2^3 \cdot 5^2$ I've used Sylow's theorem to make two claims concerning $n_G(8)$, the number of Sylow 2-subgroups of $G$:

$$
n_G(8) \equiv 1 \mod 2, \quad n_G(8) \mid 25
$$

The first claim gives that $n_G(8) \in \{1, 3, 5, 7, ...\}$ and the second gives that $n_G(8) \in \{1, 5, 25\}$ so together $n_G(8) \in \{1, 5, 25\}$.

I think I've solved the case for when $n_G(8) = 1$, in which the unique Sylow 2-subgroup $P$ is normal in $G$, so I can construct the quotient group $G/P$.  $P$ has order 8, while $G/P$ has order $200/8 = 25$, so both $P$ and $G/P$ are $p$-groups and hence solvable, hence $G$ is solvable.

I am stuck about what to do in the case that there is either 5 or 25 Sylow 2-subgroups, since in either of these instances the Sylow 2-subgroups will not be normal in $G$.  How does one go about proceeding in this instance?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/583624/11619), if not a duplicate.

Comment: Perhaps you can try a counting argument to show that you may not have 5 or 25 Sylow 2-subgroups in $G$, for otherwise the cardinality of $G$ would exceed 200.

Comment: I would advise you to consider the number of Sylow $5$-subgroups.